# ajax is not working with django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am creating a form that adds a comment to a post, it is working without ajax because ajax sends the form data as None.

**the ajax:**

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $("#myform").on("submit", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr("action"),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $("#message").html("sending...");
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        confirm('worked')
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

**the form:**

```
<form action="{% url 'newcom' Post.id%}" id="myform">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" name="comment_body" class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a comment">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="message" type="submit">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
</form>
```

**the view:**

```
def new_comment(request, post_id):
    body = request.GET.get('comment_body')
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
    Nat.objects.create(fromUser=request.user.username,   toUser=post.created_by, content="commented on your post")
    Comment.objects.create(post=post, created_by=request.user,
                          created_at=timezone.localtime(timezone.now()), comment=body)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: You are sending as POST but in your python code, you are using GET. You need to change POST to GET in your ajax.

Comment: @MilanChheda nope, the whole thing has to be done with POST - GET requests must be idempotent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<form>` element is sending the request using `GET`, and your server side code expects `GET` values. However your AJAX request is using `POST`. You need to change the AJAX request type from

```
type: 'POST'
```

to

```
type: 'GET'
```

Or you can omit the property completely, as jQuery's default is to use `GET`.

Alternatively, you can keep the AJAX method as it is and amend your Django code to receive POST variables.

Comment: GET requests __must__ be idempotent, and the view is about submitting comments, so the whole thing must be done using POST.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers good point - updated the answer to add a note about that